# MySql SHA1() allows incorrect passphrase

Tags: mysql, sha1

I'm trialling using SHA1() to encrypt passwords for an Android application which is using MySql as a remote database.

To test the implementation, I am just adding the user email address to the password and running that through SHA1(). The code snippets are from the sql on the database:

```
INSERT INTO person (
email_address,
user_password
) VALUES (
str_email,
SHA1(str_password+str_email)
);
```

The login function is:

```
SELECT id FROM person WHERE
email_address = userEmail AND
user_password = SHA1(userPassword+userEmail);
```

If I add a person with 'me@email.com' and 'abc' as the password, and then call the login function with 'me@email.com' and 'differentPassword', the procedure still returns the correct id from the person table, where I would have expected no results.

How is SHA1('correct email' + 'wrong password') matching with SHA1('correct email' + 'correct password') ?

The host I am using is a cloud host for charities. BCrypt is not available, so I am restricted to using the built in MySql functions.

Comment: Using SHA1 to "encrypt" passwords is super weak and not a really good idea.

Comment: SHA is not encryption! It's a hashing algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question to indicate the restrictions I am working under.

Comment: Try this on a mysql command line: `select 'me@email.com' + 'abc';` , which is what your `userPassword+userEmail` would do.

Comment: Running exactly that returns 0 (zero)

Comment: @DaveSav What application layer are you using? What you're doing here with `SHA1` is completely reckless because it can be cracked really, really easily. This is barely better than plain-text passwords. If your database ever leaks your users will have zero near security for their passwords. Remember, `bcrypt` is not done in MySQL but in the application layer. MySQL just stores the data.

Comment: Normally what's done is the user record is retrieved and the hashed password is compared to the hashed version of the one that was sent in. If they match, it's a successful authentication. Doing the authentication matching in the database is broken by design.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does NOT support the `+` sign for concatenation. Use `||` or `CONCAT()` instead.

Also, consider using more secure hash function.

Comment: +1 Good catch.  With the + the result is probably zero in each case.

Comment: Thanks, took me a while to catch this one :P

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question to indicate the restrictions I am working under.

Comment: Please notice that the real problem is the way you concatenate your strings, and not the hashing algorithm.

Comment: I have changed the sql to SHA1(CONCAT(str_password, str_email)) and SHA1(CONCAT(userPassword, userEmail)). Same result, it passes an incorrect password

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting all records that match when you should be selecting directly. Generally the pattern looks like:

```
SELECT id FROM person WHERE email_address=? AND password_crypted=?
```

This is where `password_crypted` is using, *at the very least*, a password specific hashing function like [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: It looks like the pattern suggested is exactly what the OP used (ignoring the use of parameters).

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question to indicate the restrictions I am working under.